# Match a number that is preceded by 's' and succeeded by '/'

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of filenames which are all like so:

```
orl_faces/s22/3.pgm
```

I am trying to extract the number which is preceded by the letter s like so:

```
re.findall(r'\[s][0-9]*','orl_faces/s22/3.pgm')
```

but it is not working, any suggestions?

Comment: Why a backslash there? Do you mean a forward slash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With zero-width positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=s)\d+
```

- `\d+` matches one or more digits, `(?<=s)` makes sure `s` precedes the digit(s)

**Edge case:**

For example, in case of the string `orl_faces3/s22/3.pgm`, it would match `3`. So, we need to come with a more restrictive pattern, based on your example, we can choose to match `/s3` as the preceding token:

```
(?<=/s)\d+
```

This could be something else, like the digits need to be followed by `/`, with a positive lookahead for `/`:

```
(?<=/s)\d+(?=/)
```

you need to figure out the exact use case though.

Another option would be to use `re.findall` and get all the matches in a list and take your pick -- but this pretty fragile and counter-productive, better to use a restrictive regular pattern.

**Example:**

```
In [64]: s = 'orl_faces/s22/3.pgm'

In [65]: re.search(r'(?<=s)\d+', s).group()
Out[65]: '22'

In [66]: s = 'orl_faces3/s22/3.pgm'

In [67]: re.search(r'(?<=s)\d+', s).group()
Out[67]: '3'

In [68]: re.search(r'(?<=/s)\d+(?=/)', s).group()
Out[68]: '22'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use group operators:

```
match = re.search(r'/s(\d+)/', my_string)
print(match.group(1))
```

Comment: Whoops I could have sworn I clicked on a javascript link my mistake, this will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> re.findall(r's(\d+)/', 'orl_faces/s22/3.pgm')
['22']
```

Comment: This will match everything with an "s" followed by integers, which could likely occur in other parts of the filename.

Comment: You're right, I missed the trailing slash requirement (in the question title).  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
re.search(r'/s([0-9]+)/','orl_faces/s22/3.pgm')[1]

'22'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expressions uses `\[s]`. This matches `[s]` **literally** (it's not matching just `s` because you put a backslash before the `[`, therefore it's interpreted literally).

---

### Code

[See it in use here](https://regex101.com/r/VfmEko/1)

```
(?<=s)\d+(?=/)
```

Ensuring `/` precedes the `s` you can use `(?<=/s)\d+(?=/)`

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/un6MWq)

```
import re

r = r"(?<=s)\d+(?=/)"
s = "orl_faces/s22/3.pgm"

print(re.findall(r, s))
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?<=s)` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes matches `s` literally
- `\d+` Matches one or more digits
- `(?=/)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches `/` literally

  - OP specified *number that is preceded by `s` and **succeeded by `/`***